# Lost connection to MySQL server at 'remote_ip:3306', system error: 2 No such file or directory

Tags: python, mysql

I've ran into this error when attempting to connect to a remote db and can't figure out why.

The local firewall settings are fine, a telnet to the IP on 3306 connects ok. Local mysql connections are fine. I've checked all the hosts.allowed, bind address, se linux.

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully this hopes someone else as I was hopeless lost on this, it was because I was configuring the SSL without ensuring that the location of the key file etc we're actually valid:

eg, the dict used config passed to `mysql.connector.connect`:

```
config['client_flags'] = [ClientFlag.SSL]
config['ssl_ca'] = ssl_ca
config['ssl_cert'] = ssl_cert
config['ssl_key'] = ssl_key
config['ssl_verify_cert'] = True
```

The way the error was worded made me think it was to do with the remote machine not the local code.